# Glassfish server - start in same command prompt window

Tags: console2, glassfish

When I run `asadmin start-domain` it launches glassfish in a new command prompt window. I want to launch it from the same window I launch the command from. The idea is I want to launch GF3 from a Console2 tab and leave it running there rather than having multiple GF cmd windows.

Comment: Are you launching it from an actual command prompt or a GF console window?

Comment: Actual command prompt. Actually its a batch file with the commands to set up the window environment first, but calling the batch file is like type the commands manually.

Comment: Ok, as long as it's a real cmd then see my answer.

Comment: you can use `nohup` so that even were you to close the window or log out, the command, `start-domain`, would still be running and glassfish would stay up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a console app in the same cmd window as the batch file you can use `call`

```
call asadmin start-domain
```

Which will run the console app and then return to the batch file, without creating a new window.

You can also start it off in it's own thread so to speak, and also in the same window

```
start /b asadmin start-domain
```

`call` is generally better, but it's up to you.